# table header is fixed and scrollable body

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need a `table` for list of records where table header is fixed and scrollable body inside a div. 
`Div` which is non scrollable but expands its height to certain length according to certain number of records and if table has more than that records the `DIV` need to be fixed position.

My main concern is to avoid user to scroll the page. Instead, I want him to scroll table which is inside the `Div`, but if the list has less number of records div outline border looking awkward.

I am working out this table in `MVC View`, but couldn't get the expected result. Any sample code is appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

```
.FixedHeightDiv
{
 float:right;
 height: 250px;
 width:250px; 
 padding:3px; 
 background:#f00;
}
.Content
{
 height:224px;
 overflow:auto;
 background:#fff;
}



<div class="FixedHeightDiv">
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="Content">
your content  
your content
your content
your content
your content
your content
your content
your content
your content
your content
your content
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/PyramidTek/hrn6fwb9/

Comment: if this answered your question. please select it as answer.